# how to display image on gridview if database table contain URL of image?

Tags: asp.net

For ex URl is http://media.google.com/ImageServer/Public/2016/August/EnglishBanner/sidebanner-labor-day-2016.jpg

I just give sample example of URl
Please help me

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>         
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImageUrl_column") %>' height="100px" Width="100px" />             
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

Comment: I got solution Thanks